# How would you systematically and intuitively approach this? Statistics and Probability Question

Tags: probability

The problem in question is as follows:

A fair die with faces numbered $1, ... , 6$ is thrown repeatedly. What is the probability I get exactly one $4$ and one $5$ before the first $6$?

**My thoughts:**

I understand that we are supposed to do this question with the **OR** rule, considering the cases where the $6$ first arises. The answer given is

[image]

However, I can not intuitively think about the binomial coefficients. I think that the method they are using is basically saying that if you have a string of numbers of length $n$ with the last one being $6$ then you have $n-1$ positions to chose from for the $5$ and $4$ and thus $\binom{n-1}{2}$ and then we have to multiply that by $2$  we can interchange $a$ and $b$ (i.e. we have a permutaiton rather than a combination) and finally multiply that by $3^{n-3}$ as we have $3$ choices for each of the remaining. Then divide by $6^n$ to get the desired probability. However, I do not find this intuitive since I had to really think if I had to do $n-1!$ instead since all the other values could b different to each other (I later discounted this thought since the other values could all take 3 different possibilities so their possible rearrangement is calculated for)

**My question:**

How would one systematically and intuitively approach this type of question?

Answer (score 4):

First, recognize that all times the die landed on $1,2,3$ don't matter.

Consider then *only* the first three rolls which had any of $4,5,6$ rolled, having ignored any and all $1$'s, $2$'s, and $3$'s which occurred before inbetween, or after, and having ignored all rolls which occurred after the third of the "larger" numbers which were rolled.  There are $3^3$ equally likely different possibilities for the sequence of the first three large results, being `444`, `445`, `446`, `454`, `455`, `456`, ..., `666`.

Only two of which correspond to having had both exactly one $4$ and exactly one $5$ as having occurred before the first $6$, corresponding to the sequence `456` or `546`.  Any of the other possible sequences such as `444` or `654` will have broken the requirements, `444` having broken the condition that exactly one $4$ occurred before the first $6$ occurred because more than one $4$ has occurred., or `654` breaking the condition that exactly one $4$ occurred before the first $6$ since *zero* $4$'s occurred before the first $6$, and so on...

> The event I refer to here, `456` where we only kept track of the first three of the times we rolled a number equal to $4,5,$ or $6$ if we were to have kept track of all of the rolls would include but not be limited to `4561111222333456...`, `1114222253333364444...`, `1452226...` and so on... The point is that all of the numbers which aren't among the first three occurrences of any of 4,5,6 may be "blurred out" and ignored, which *heavily* simplifies the problem, allowing us to look at a finite sample space... one which we can show is equiprobable.

The probability is then:

$$\dfrac{2}{27}$$

---

To explain the book's answer, they chose to do this the hard way and worked with the infinite sample space.  They first broke into cases based on which roll it was that the first $6$ occurred.

In order for it to be the case that the $k$'th roll was the first roll where a $6$ occurred, first... there must have been a $6$ that occurred on the $k$'th roll.  This occurs with probability $\frac{1}{6}$.

Then, to have it match our required condition among the previous $k-1$ rolls you would need exactly one of these to be a $4$ and exactly one of these to be a $5$.  Pick which two of the $k-1$ rolls it was to be the $4$ and $5$ simultaneously and then pick which of those two was the $4$ and which was the $5$.  This can be done in $\binom{k-1}{2}\cdot 2$ ways (*or more simply, $(k-1)(k-2)$ ways... there wasn't much reason to use a binomial coefficient here rather than simple multiplication.  Further, it appears the book's answer worded it in an even stranger fashion by instead of picking the two positions occupied by a $4$ and $5$, they instead picked the $k-3$ positions occupied by $1$'s, $2$'s and $3$'s... note that $\binom{k-1}{k-3}=\binom{k-1}{2}$*).  To have our position designated to be occupied by a $4$ actually be occupied by a $4$, this occurs with probability $\frac{1}{6}$ and similarly for our position designated to be occupied by a $5$ also occurs with probability $\frac{1}{6}$.

Finally, all remaining positions would need to have been occupied by $1$'s, $2$'s, or $3$'s, the probability of this occurring for each position individually would be $\frac{3}{6}$ and for all $k-3$ of the positions with probability $\left(\frac{3}{6}\right)^{k-3}$

Combining all of this together, we get a result of:

$$\sum\limits_{k=3}^\infty \binom{k-1}{2}\cdot 2\cdot \frac{1}{6}\cdot \frac{1}{6}\cdot \frac{1}{6}\cdot \left(\frac{3}{6}\right)^{k-3}$$

You can then factor and expand this using known results about infinite sums to what they have above in the books answer... this of course simplifying to the same answer of $\dfrac{2}{27}$, but having gone through massively frustrating algebraic manipulations dealing with infinite sums and casework...

It is *fine........* if you had no better ideas, it gets you to an answer, however it is hardly how I would have approached the problem.  You saw how easily I arrived at the answer above, being able to do all of the required arithmetic calculations in my head almost instantly.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I have a couple of questions. 1) Do we ignore the numbers in between since we want to only consider the order in which $4,5,6$ occur? 2) So what was the point in using the binomial coefficients as the mark scheme suggests?

Comment: The idea for me is: roll until you get a $4,$ $5,$ or $6.$ Repeat the process three times. If you have not succeeded by this time to roll exactly one each of $4$ and $5$ before rolling the first $6,$ you never will. And the point of the binomial coefficients is that whoever made the "official" answer didn't think of this simpler approach.

Comment: @MathsWizzard added an explanation of the book's answer.  I can not recommend using the book's approach unless you are completely unable to spot the simplifications to the problem that I used.

Comment: As I wrote, I think the book really meant to do a combination rather than a permutation, and then the idea was you can roll *either* $4$ or $5$ for the first "non-chosen" roll (whence the $\frac26$ factor). But admittedly that's just trying to read someone's mind.

Comment: It occurs to me that the reason the "official" answer did not use the simplifying observation about irrelevant rolls might be that this is one of a series of problems that is meant to develop a certain methodical approach to these problems that relies on counting the total number of rolls until some event occurs (in this case, the first $6$). And suddenly saying "but in this case ignore the total number of rolls, just consider these three rolls" would be a distraction. But we can't know if that is the case without much more context.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the question were this:

> What is the probability that in $n$ rolls of a fair die with sides numbered $1,2,3,4,5,6,$ the number $6$ comes up for the first time on the last roll, and the numbers $4$ and $5$ each come up once?

The only way for this to happen is in the first $n-1$ rolls you get $n-3$ rolls that come up $1,$ $2,$ or $3$, one $4,$ and one $5,$ and the $n$th roll is $6.$

The approach in the given answer is that there are $\binom{n-1}{n-3}$ places in the sequence that could be occupied by $1,$ $2,$ or $3$, so this is the number of different sequences in which we can get the two events "$1,$ $2,$ or $3$" and "$4$ or $5$" for the events we want to count.
For each of those sequences we have a $\frac36$ probability for each "$1,$ $2,$ or $3$" event, a $\frac26$ probability for the first "$4$ or $5$" event, and a $\frac16$ probability for the second "$4$ or $5$" event (since the second "$4$ or $5$" event has to be a different number than the first one, leaving only one possible number).

There are other ways to do the counting that come up with the same answer, for example you can count $\binom{n-1}{2}$ ways to choose two places in the first $n-1$ places where $4$ or $5$ get rolled,
or you can count the number of permutations of $2$ non-repeating items chosen from $n-1,$ where the items are positions in the sequence of rolls, the first item chosen is the position in which $4$ is rolled, and the second choice is the position in which $5$ is rolled.
If you go with permutations then you have probabilities $\frac16$ and $\frac16$ for the $4$ and $5$ instead of $\frac26$ and $\frac16$, since the permutation specifies which of the two numbers came first.

Counting total outcomes and then dividing by $6^n$ is an option too. It's all equivalent calculations: there will be so many factors of $3$ and so many other factors in the numerator and $6^n$ factors of $6$ in the denominator either way.

The given answer to the original question then says that since the first $6$ could come up on rolls $3,$ $4,$ $5,$ and so forth (omitting the first and second roll since there cannot be exactly one $4$ and one $5$ in those cases), we can add up the probabilities for $n = 3,4,5,\ldots.$

As shown in another answer, this is not the simplest way to do this.